# Почему иконка размытая?

Tags: android, icon

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему текст вроде чекий, а иконка не четкая? 
Саму иконку брал с официального  [сайта](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_date_range)

Пробовал все возможные размеры, а она все равно размытая(

Comment: а возьмите svg формат

Comment: Тестируете на реальном устройстве, или на виртуальном?
+, какая версия Android? 
Начиная с 5 версии лучше использовать вектора.
Попробуйте использовать пример с [этого](https://materialdesignicons.com/) сайта

Comment: @nonews я зашел на сайт скачал xml файлы иконок и вставил в свое приложение) и это поомогло спасибо большое) 
Напишите ответ, я его отмечу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте взять иконку с [этого](https://materialdesignicons.com/) сайта.

Если используете Android версию 5.0 и выше - лучше всего использовать вектор.

Так же, далеко не всегда виртуальное устройство показывает истинную картину, в конечном тестировании лучше тестировать на реальном.